# What is causing BadRequestException when calling the ExecuteStatement operation on Aurora Serverless db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds, amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

I have a lambda function that retrieves records from AWS Aurora Serverless db. Now I thought of adding api gateway to trigger the lambda function but I get this error
Connect an AWS Lambda function triggered by API Gateway to Aurora Serverless MySQL database.

```
[ERROR] BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: 
Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.x.xx.xxx' (using password: YES); Error code: 1045; SQLState: 28000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 11, in handler
    sql="SELECT * FROM ecomdev.Customer;"
```

What is causing BadRequestException when calling the ExecuteStatement operation on Aurora Serverless db. I have used AWS CDK to create the stacks.
I went through this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/941886/connect-an-aws-lambda-function-triggered-by-api-gateway-to-aurora-serverless-mys) But it follows a different which I feel is not necessary. Please help me out if you have encountered this error.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1045 [apparently means](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-access-denied/) 'Access denied'. Have you set the credentials properly in your Lambda? Does the lambda use the right execution role? Seems to be some more good info [here](https://awsauroralabsmy.com/serverless/dataapi/).